# Facebook applinks opens browser on Android

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I'm trying to implement the applinks. Maybe I understand it utterly wrong, but I'm expecting this workflow:

- create/enhance a web page with the meta headers (other content doesn't matter)
- enhance the app with intent-filter responding to myapp scheme
- post a link to this web page to Facebook
- click this post on Facebook
- it should open my app (or Google Play)

Is that correct?

The web page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="myapp://something/something">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="packagename">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="App Name">
    <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.location.replace('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The app can be opened using the Intent (tested with adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "myapp://something/something")

Now I create a post with link to this web page on Facebook (BTW will Messenger do, so I don't need to pollute my wall with testing?). Click it in the Facebook Android app.

I expect it to open my app, but it always opens the browser. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: What is the link to the website? Have you run it through the debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ ?

Comment: The the website link is http://lovelikeorhate.eu/question/3 (the number is changing of course). But it really only responds with what's in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Fixing issues it found resolved the issue. It was missing og:type and og:title - applinks documentation didn't mention anything about that but it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website must include og:type and og:title meta tags for it to work. This is a useful link for detecting these problems:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/